# Sum then divide by issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I'm trying to sum two columns and then divide by another, example;

```
'''SUM(M.Bonus) + ISNULL(SUM(Q.Bonus),0) / SUM(Salary.M)'''
```

`Q.Bonus` contains `null` values. If I remove ISNULL it gives me the correct answer but won't calculate some because of null values. When I do it with the `ISNULL` it just gives me the outcome of the sum.

Comment: Could you share the full query. SUM implies you're grouping on something but Q.Bonus isn't in an aggregate so unless that's what you are grouping on I'd expect you to get an error.

Comment: IS NULL should have had a SUM after, apologies.

Comment: You might want to add some parenthesis also to ensure your math is what you think it is. I am guessing you want SUM((M.Bonus + ISNULL(Q.Bonus, 0)) / M.Salary)

Comment: @SeanLange, Jackpot - Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Wyseguy don't forget to mark the answer that helped you as correct...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your very brief question I would guess that you have a basic [BODMAS](https://www.theschoolrun.com/what-is-bodmas) maths problem

```
SUM(M.Bonus) + ISNULL(SUM(Q.Bonus),0) / SUM(Salary.M)
```

should probably be

```
(SUM(M.Bonus) + ISNULL(SUM(Q.Bonus),0)) / SUM(Salary.M)
```

Note the extra brackets!

Without further context and examples code it's really difficult to see what you are really asking.  See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further info on [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct `ISNULL()` function syntax.
You need to take care `devide by zero` error as below.

This query gives you answer.

```
SUM(ISNULL(M.Bonus,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Q.Bonus,0)) / ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(M.Salary,0)),1)
```

**Note**: I think that you may wrote salary alias wrongly. So, I have corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something along these lines. You only need one aggregate. Also parenthesis to ensure the calculation is performed correctly.

```
SUM((M.Bonus + ISNULL(Q.Bonus, 0)) / M.Salary)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need additional parentheses.  But I would recommend using `NULLIF()` to avoid divide-by-zero errors:

```
(SUM(M.Bonus) + COALESCE(SUM(Q.Bonus), 0)) / NULLIF(SUM(Salary.M), 0)
```